# Search text in specific active category - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function

```
 public function searchFile(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'text' => 'required'
    ]);
    $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
    $data['page_title'] = 'File Search';
    $data['category'] = Category::all();
    $data['menu_cat'] = Category::take(6)->get();
    $data['subcategory'] = SubCategory::orderBy('name','ASC')->get();
    $data['title'] = 0;
    $data['files'] = File::where('title','like',"%$request->text%")->orderBy('download','DESC')->paginate(12);
    $data['general'] = GeneralSetting::first();
    return view('home.search-file',$data);
}
```

Currently it searches in all available categories in the table

how can i modify to search it related to one category ?

and can i use "if" in it

Like if category 16 is opened search only in this category

Comment: what do u mean by category is opened ???

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass a category_id to your request, then you you could do :

```
$data['category'] = $request->has('category_id') ? Category::find($request->input('category_id')) : Category::all();
```

Or in Laravel 5.5+, use $request->[filled](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_filled)() instead of $request->[has](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_has)() ($request->has() return true even if category_id == null)

```
$data['category'] = $request->filled('category_id') ? Category::find($request->input('category_id')) : Category::all();
```

We use here a ternary instead of a if/else structure. In if/else it would have been :

```
if ($request->filled('category_id'))
    $data['category'] = Category::find($request->input('category_id'));
else 
    $data['category'] = Category::all();
```